# Enabling Ethernet connections in my whole household?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I need to figure out how to finish the setup of Ethernet cables throughout my whole home. Basically, all the routing through walls is done as well as the Ethernet wall sockets and such. I'm a complete beginner but I want to finish this job. All the Ethernet cables route to a panel in my house. The modem/router set up is not near the panel and it can't be moved there.

What tools do I need to finish this process? My main goal is just to be able to have a working Ethernet connection in all the sockets in the house. I already have a patch panel and some extra Ethernet cables.

Image of panel:

[image]

EDIT: Router/modem can't be moved to the panel.

Comment: This might get lost, since it was posted in a comment under an answer below, but what the asker is calling a patch panel is actually a telephone hub: https://imgur.com/a/dTGUheB So it actually doesn't have any rj45 ports

Comment: Two things spring to mind:

If all the routing through walls is done as well as the Ethernet wall sockets and such, what problem remains?

More clearly when the modem/router is not near the panel, why can't it be moved there? Why can you not use longer cables?

Comment: It sounds like this belongs on DIY.SE instead of Superuser.

Comment: Did you wire all this yourself?  I've seen houses with existing ethernet jacks and cat5 runs which were meant for VOIP (or whatever else) and didn't use standard wiring schemes.  Just a heads-up.  {Also, probably a silly question, but: is your goal to enable ethernet throughout your household, or to provide _internet_ access via that ethernet?  I think we're all going to assume the latter, but the former would be a much simpler problem if that's all you need...}

Comment: do you want to do it cheap, or right?  If "right"" I'll do an answer about patch panels specifically.

Comment: @TylerH This is 100% a networking question.  There's nothing DIY related here.

Answer (score 32):

Your setup should look like this (warning: ASCII art)

```
        |
        | internet drop - ADSL/fiber/cable
        |
+-------+-----ISP-supplied router----------+
[       Whatever port the ISP uses         ]
[                                          ]
[       one RJ45 port, out of usually 4    ]
+-------+----------------------------------+
        |
        | Ethernet cable (cat 5e or better), bridging the distance between
        | the router and the panel location, possibly through a wall
        |
+-------+-------Switch you need to buy -------------------------------+
[       one of the RJ45 port. Switch may have a dedicated (higher-    ]
[ bandwidth?) "uplink" port, if not any of the ports will do.         ]
[                                                                     ]
[       other RJ45 ports                                              ]
+-------+-+-+---------------------------------------------------------+
        | | |
        | | | Ethernet cables (cat 5e or better) - the blue ones in your photo -
        | | | bridging the distance to each jack, through the walls
        | | |
        Ethernet jacks
```

### The Cables

Your cables seem to be terminated with an RJ45 plug - plug them directly into the switch. You say one cable doesn't have an RJ45 plug - you should crimp a plug on it, using a [crimper tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=rj45+crimp+tool). Weird that whoever pulled the cables only crimped some cables...

An alternative is to terminate all the cables in a RJ45 patch panel, and bridge that into the switch with several short (~20cm?) pre-made patch cables.

### The Switch

You need to buy a switch. It should:

- Get power from somewhere. Switches usually come with a converter brick (wall-wart).

  - If the router+switch support it, you might be able to get power from the router using PoE (Power-over-Ethernet)
- Have as many ports as you need, plus a few spare. I guess 8-port should do it.
- Support gigabit (AKA GigE, 1GbE or 10/100/1000). If you get lower speed (100mbps), you'll limit your internal traffic speed, and also internet speed if/when you get a >100mbps connection from your ISP.

  - There are 2.5gbps switches, but they're expensive and probably not worth it for now.
- Be unmanaged. There are managed switches which have a management panel/UI to control individual ports, but for a home use that's usually not needed.

### Wi-Fi

The question doesn't mention it, but you probably want wi-fi in your house as well. With a wired Ethernet backhaul, you're in an excellent position for it!

The ISP-supplied router will usually be a Wi-Fi access point - you can use that wherever the signal is strong enough. You can check the signal strength in various locations using [a wifi-analyzer app](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi+signal+strength+app).

If you want to improve signal in a location, you can buy a Wi-Fi access point, connect it to your awesome Ethernet setup, and have Wi-Fi in that room as well! The access point will usually have an additional RJ45 Ethernet port where you can connect an additional wired device.

I won't go into further Wi-Fi solutions like mesh kits.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in my house.  The only thing I'd add is that if you look up the manufacturer of that wall panel, you'll probably find that they sell a network switch that will snap right into the mounting holes like the telephone patch panel does.

Comment: Depending on the router currently in used it might be possible to power the switch via Power over Ethernet, removing the extra need for a wall plug near the switch/patchpanel. Also I have seen some switches with a dedicated uplink (=higher bandwith) port. If OP gets one of those, also fine, just use that port for the line to the router

Comment: This is a great typical setup.  I have one variation in my home set up in that the router and the modem are two separate devices.  I find most ISP provided device are an all in one combination modem wifi router and switch these days.

Answer (score 10):

#### Short Answer

Assuming I'm not misunderstanding your level experience with networking, it sounds like the only thing left is a networking switch.

The modem/router does the actual routing but has a limited amount of ports, and the patch panel is just a termination point for the data lines throughout your house. So the what you need now is to have every "active" port on the patch panel to be connected to a switch with ethernet cables, which is itself then connected to your modem/router in some way.

#### Further Explanation

Here are a couple of examples I quickly pulled from google of what you should more or less end up with - [example 1](https://preview.redd.it/oq4q6tz4y8k51.jpg?width=4032&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=b83fe39b32ca93e2cbf68d793fbacaed96f523d5), [example 2](https://preview.redd.it/cuic7gw8i9771.jpg?width=2268&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=51e914f25a7f1f9f4201f50761a2702f18e9c416). These are more involved setups but the important piece is what the path panel connects to, the switch.

So you should end up with a flow of traffic that goes from device connected to ethernet port in wall (network drop), then terminates at patch panel, then connected to a switch, which is then connected to a modem/router.

Switches generally come in two flavours- "dumb" and "smart", or more practically, *managed* and *un-managed*. Managed switches usually give you some sort of control panel that allows you to do things like disable and enable ports, change speeds and undertake more advanced configuration. Unmanaged switches are basically plug in and forget. For getting started I'd recommend getting a dumb switch, it's going to be less hassle to setup and they're cheaper.

I don't have any specific dumb switch suggestions so I'd google around. Amazon probably has a good selection depending on where you live, reference reviews and pick one for your needs. The only things you're really looking for in a dumb switch are the `number of ports` and their `speed`. Number of ports to match how many network drops you've run.

Network port speed is the maximum speed you'll ever get on that connection. So if you get a `10/100` switch you'll never get internet speeds above a theoretical 100Mbps. This isn't just in reference to your internet package with your internet service provider but internal communications as well. You probably don't have to worry about this, so to simplify my recommendation is that you pick up at least a 1GB switch. You'll most commonly see these denoted with `Gigabit`, `1GbE`, or `10/100/1000`.

#### Connecting Everything

The switch is a pretty straightforward piece of equipment, it has a power cable and ports, with a processor inside to direct internet traffic. Once on, cables can be plugged in arbitrarily. Without getting too deep into it, the way that a dumb switch routes traffic can be considered *port agnostic*.

This goes for you modem/router as well. As long as you can get everything connected to the switch in some combination of ports, everything will get directed just fine.

You should end up with every terminated patch panel port being connected to a port on a the switch (client devices), and a single port having the modem/router plugged into it. If you have a network drop near where the modem currently is, then you can just connect the modem to it, and then the corresponding patch panel port to the switch. It'll be functionally identical to having the modem near it and plugged in directly into the switch.

Feel free to leave a comment if you have additional questions, I'll try to get back to you within a reasonable timeframe.

***Source:*** *I am a technical architect / systems administrator for an IT company.*

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you need an ethernet switch with enough ports for all the sockets in your house.  You then jumper the cables from the panel to the switch (and when you want to use the network ports you plug in to them on the other side).

Some pictures of the patch panel would be useful here as we don't know how the cables terminate in it.  If the job has been competently done by a professional and was set up for ethernet, you may have RJ45 jacks in the panel - which is easy.  If not, you will need to get a patch panel and punch tool and terminate the connectors onto the patch panel.  (A patch panel is a row of RJ45 connectors on the front with a mechanism to connect it to cables at the back).  If you do need to punch down your own patch panel you will want to get a cable tester (about $10) so you can check you have punched down all the wires correctly and to the correct wiring standard [ there are 2 common ones ]

Comment: Here is a picture of the panel the cables route to: https://imgur.com/a/dTGUheB I bought a patch panel that does terminate RJ45 connectors (to my knowledge) as well. There is also only one cable that is just wires and not the actual connector.

Comment: I guess my main issue is wiring my router to a switch that is in the location of my panel. I could move the modem/router if there were connections near the main panel but there is not. So I'm left with figuring out a way to connect these two together with the puzzle pieces that the home builder left.

Comment: That wiring is not clear to me and looks just a bit dodge.  Assuming you only care about the blue cables it looks like they are crimped with RJ45 connectors (not ideal, but works in practice) - in which case you can just plug those directly into your switch and call it a day.

Comment: That's not a network patch panel. That's a telephone hub. It connects all of the ports together, which you'd want if you were using the cables for telephones, but you're not. You need an actual patch panel that has RJ45 ports

Comment: @jonah To explain what Cody is talking about. Telephone signals has lower requirements than ethernet signals (low/high bandwidth). Your telephone hub will destroy the electrical signals used in ethernet, and you will be lucky to get 100MB/s. Since you spend the time and money for cables, you should install a proper network patch panel, that preserves the UTP twist. Additionally, your installer likely messed up if they didn't know these things. If they treated the UTP like telephone cables, they could have also spliced cables, which is a no go for ethernet...

Comment: My reading of the picture is different to cody and @aron.  The beige cables appear to have been punched down to go to a phone system, however the blue cables are most likely crimped for ethernet.  This is not uncommon.

Comment: I agree with @davidgo, and the beige cables are probably exactly what goes to his modem in the first place (in which case it would be moveable down there with a bit of trickery).

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the picture closely, it seems there are just loose, terminated Ethernet cables which presumably go to the socket locations in your house.

As everyone has said already, a cheap unmanaged switch will allow all of these to communicate with each other and with your broadband router.

Simply connect all these Ethernet cables to the switch and a single Ethernet cable from the LAN or WAN/LAN port on your router. Then all points on the network will be able to communicate with each other and the router (your router should allocate IP addresses to all connected computers using DHCP) so hopefully will work straight away.

If the router is not near to this area OR to one of the network sockets which have been installed you could use a powerline adapter kit to connect your router to the new switch.

You will need domestic power socket for the switch and power for each powerline adapter if required.

So setup either looks like:

Internet router <--> eth cable <—> switch <—blue cables to wall plates and your devices

OR

Internet router <—>powerline adapter kit <—> switch <—> blue cables

OR

Internet router <—> wall plate <—> 1 of the blue cables <—> switch <—> remainder of blue cables out to other devices

I think I’m just hashing together other answers from above here but maybe this is helpful in solving the router location issue.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have explained the need for a switch and Jonathan has provided an ascii art pic showing what needs to be connected to what. However, I thought a concrete example might be reassuring. The photo below (deliberately not resized to ease reading) shows what I have in the cellar. From bottom to top:

1. power strip with PSUs for route/modem and switch
2. modem/router (a Fritzbox; popular in Germany)
3. 16-port Netgear GS116Ev2 switch (configuration not required unless you want VLANs and traffic shaping)
4. 12-port Telegaertner mini distributor (the cellar-end of the network cables; the other ends are in different rooms around the house)
5. 6-port Telegaertner mini distributor (making a total of 18 ports, of which only 14 are cabled)

A few extra notes:

1. 14 ports around the house might seem excessive, but the wall panels around the house are all 2-port panels and the cost of the extra cable and small effort to push them through the conduits was tiny compared to the cost of getting a workman to cut channels into the concrete walls for the conduits.
2. I think the only cable that may not be clear is the white one coming down the left: this connects the internet/cable connector, which is high on the wall and outside the photo, to the router/modem near the bottom of the photo.

[a wall in my cellar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCVAX.jpg)

Comment: Nice! I assume the 12-port/4-port "mini distributor"s are patch panels?

Comment: What is the purpose of the Telegaertner devices?

Comment: @NickMatteo: Looks like to protect the cables running through the wall from typical damage associated with insertion and removal of plugs.

Comment: Yes, the mini distributors are one end, if you see of what I mean, of a patch panel and as Nick suggested, not having ot handle the cable directly should make it last longer. Telegaernter don't/didn't do 16 port distributors so I was forced to accept 12 port + 4 port.

Comment: doh ... i mean 12+6 not 12+4.